# CSS / IE 7 problem

Tags: css

I am having a hell of a time figuring out what went wrong with one of my buddie's sites regarding the CSS navigation menus.

Here is the link to his site
http://www.rpmafitness.com

If you mouse over the About Us nav button, the menu drops down directly below it and everything works prefectly. But if you mouse over the Classes and Events, the nav pops up below and to the right and I cant figure out why. And to top it off, its just IE 7. IE 8, Chrome, FF work fine.

Any CSS gurus who want to take a peek and see what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: A screrenshot of the problem would be useful. People without IE can't reprodue it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. On this line:

```
<li><a href="http://www.rpmafitness.com/page/classes-events.aspx">Classes and Events</a><ul style="width: 110px;">
```

I would add `style="width: 75px;"` to the `<li>`. Adjust the width as needed if it isn't wide enough.